# Powers of an Orthogonal Matrix

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I have the following orthogonal matrix:

$M_{5,5}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

My aim here is to diagonalize it and check some interesting properties of powers of $M$. Then I proceed to express $M$ as $M=P.D.P^{-1}$

```
M={
{0,1,0,0,0},
{1,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,1,0},
{0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,1,0,0}
}
{d, P} = Eigensystem[M]
P = Transpose[P]
d = DiagonalMatrix[d]
Round[P.d.Inverse[P]] == M (*True*)
Round[P.d.d.Inverse[P]]  == M.M (*True*)
```

This means that $M^k = P.D^k.P^{-1}$ so the eigenvalues of $A^k$ are $\lambda^k=\{D^k_{1,1},D^k_{2,2},D^k_{3,3},D^k_{4,4},D^k_{5,5}\}$

but when I compare $\lambda^2$ with the eigenvalues of $M^2$ the output is **False**.

Now I start to think that $M^2$ can be written in 2 different ways:

$M^2 = P.D^2.P^{-1}$ which we have seen it is true.

$M^2 = Q.D'.Q^{-1}$ this means that other eigen decomposition exists in ${M^2}$.

Can someone tell me If I'm wrong? If true why $M^2$ can be written in these two expressions?

**EDIT:**

Let's make the eigen decomposition of $M^2$ and check for equalities:

```
{dp, Pp} = Eigensystem[M.M]
Pp = Transpose[Pp]
dp = DiagonalMatrix[dp]
Round[Pp.dp.Inverse[Pp]] == M.M (*True*)    
Round[P.d.d.Inverse[P]]  == M.M (*True*)
d==dp (*False*)
P == Pp (*False*)
```

We have seen that Eigenvectors of $M$ and $M^2$ are different and Eigenvalues of $M^2$ are not $\lambda^2$, but yet you can write $M^2$ in two different expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The diagonalization of a matrix is only unique up to an ordering of the eigenvalues. What is happening here is that the Eigenvalues in `dp` and `d.d` are ordered differently. One easily verifies that

```
Simplify[SortBy[Diagonal[d.d], N] == SortBy[Diagonal[dp], N]]
```

Returns `True`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `M` and `M.M` both have the eigenvalue `1` with multiplicity `2` or higher (the multiplicity of `1` for `M` is `2` while it is `3` for `M.M`).

That means that the eigenvectors to be returned by `Eigensystem` belonging to eigenvalue `1` are not uniquely defined - any orthogonal basis of the eigenspace of eigenvalue `1` would do.

Moreover, the eigenvalues of `M.M` are sorted in a different order than those of `M`:

```
M = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}};
{λ, P} = Eigensystem[M];
P = Transpose[P];

{λp, Pp} = Eigensystem[M.M];
Pp = Transpose[Pp];
Max[Abs[λ^2 - λp[[{1, 2, 3, 5, 4}]] // N]]
```

> 1.11022*10^-16